# Is there any way to make django admin search for multiple terms, maybe seperated with a comma?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have this code, but it honestly works selectively:

```
  def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(Name_of_adminclass, self).get_search_results(
                                           request, queryset, search_term)
        search_words = search_term.split(',')

        if search_words:
            q_objects = [Q(**{field + '__iexact': word})
                            for field in self.search_fields
                            for word in search_words]
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, q_objects))
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Also for what ever reason, it seems to disable the filters so that they don't work, searching for exact terms with a comma sometimes works, anyone can help?